# how to find a specific record Map value in flutter sembast?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test, sembast

I'm using sembast in a flutter app, I have a  `getAll()` function that looks like the following:

```
Future getFavorites() async {
    List favSnapshot = await _favFolder.find(await _db);
    if (favSnapshot.length > 0) {
      return favSnapshot;
     
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and it returns the following:

```
[
  Record(favorites, 1) {hello: worls}, 
  Record(favorites, 2) {name: Daredevil, season: 1, episode: 3}, 
  Record(favorites, 3) {name: Daredevil, season: 1, episode: 2}, 
  Record(favorites, 4) {name: Daredevil, season: 3, episode: 2}, 
  Record(favorites, 5) {name: Daredevil, season: 1, episode: 13}, 
  Record(favorites, 6) {name: Daredevil, season: 1, episode: 1}]
```

How can I check if I have `{name: Daredevil, season: 1, episode: 13}` in my data?

Comment: You could try to use a combined filter like this: https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/issues/20#issuecomment-470487969

Comment: Thank, that's worked fine. but, I have to check all fields one by one if they exists using multiple Filter.equals(). is there a way to check the whole document at once?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to create a filter that checks whether a record "contains" some data.

You can combine filters:

```dart
/// Filter record that contains the same field (i.e. check multiple fields value)
Filter containsMapFilter(Map<String, Object?> map) {
  return Filter.and(
      map.entries.map((e) => Filter.equals(e.key, e.value)).toList());
}

var snapshots = await store.find(db,
    finder: Finder(
        filter: containsMapFilter(
            {'name': 'Daredevil', 'season': 1, 'episode': 13})));
```

You can use a custom filter:

```dart
/// Filter record that contains the same field (i.e. check multiple fields value)
Filter containsMapFilter(Map<String, Object?> map) {
  return Filter.custom((record) {
    var data = record.value as Map;
    for (var entry in map.entries) {
      if (data[entry.key] != entry.value) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}

var snapshots = await store.find(db,
    finder: Finder(
        filter: containsMapFilter(
            {'name': 'Daredevil', 'season': 1, 'episode': 13})));
```

If you are looking for an exact match you can use a custom filter and the DeepCollectionEquality from the collection package:

```dart
// import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

/// Filter record that contains the same field (i.e. check multiple fields value)
Filter mapEqualsFilter(Map<String, Object?> map) {
  return Filter.custom((record) {
    var data = record.value as Map;
    return DeepCollectionEquality().equals(map, data);
  });
}

var snapshots = await store.find(db,
    finder: Finder(
        filter: mapEqualsFilter(
            {'name': 'Daredevil', 'season': 1, 'episode': 13})));
```